# How can I get User object from its user id in Firebase Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Suppose I have made user in Firebase in Android with its UID is `rka1KNwIA2elmmHOv97AZbj9KDs1` and I want the `User` object which is similar like **user** which we will get from following piece of code

FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

[image]

Comment: Do you have that user stored in the database? If so, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I have added the Scrrenshot

Comment: I suggest adding the screenshot to your question not in a link, also your question is not very clear.

Comment: Done, I have added the screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve that, first, you need to create a class:

```
public class User {
    public String imageURL, mail, misno, name, phon;

    public User() {}
}
```

Now, to get the `rka1KNwIA2elmmHOv97AZbj9KDs1` object as an object of the `User` class, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("User").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        Log.d("TAG", user.name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

I have added a log statement to see that is printed out in the logcat the name of the user.